# Setting up xampp for uploading files

Tags: php, linux, xampp

I have xampp set up properly but when I try to upload a file with a page I have written it fails. I've changed the upload file path in `/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini` to `/opt/lampp/tmp/` but when I print

`echo $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];`

in a php page it prints out `/tmp/phpjfsfjal`

I'm sure this is all about permissions but I don't know what set up I should have

Running whoami from a php page shows 'nobody'

Can anyone help?

Comment: i think that `/tmp/` it's a relative location. Have you verified that it's a permission denied issue? when uploading files you have to be sure the file size does not exceed the limit for your configuration, if that is not the case, what permissions does the `/opt/lampp/tmp` folder has?

Comment: Ahh I assumed it was absolute. That makes a lot more sense now and I've sorted it. Thanks